# I can't remote control my desktop from the external internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, remote-desktop, ip

I've done everything. I can't remote desktop control my PC From outside my local network (external internet) via Windows Remote Desktop.

After lots of troubleshooting:

1. I can log in to my RDP host via the local network with the hostname or local IPV4 Address. So the server details are correct (account name, hostname, password).
2. When searching for what's my IP Address on Google (I get this IP: 187.216.212.201) It's different from what shows on my modem router getaway page (I get this IP: 139.54.239.16). And both are different from my local IP Address  (I get this IP: 172.169.215.73) -definitely as they are external vs internal-.
3. I went to my Windows firewall and allowed the remote desktop port 3389. And I used port 3389 everywhere (router, pc, firewall...), so I don't mess up any port forwarding setting.

**So I have concluded The problem stems from the external IP Address... But at which part, this is where I need your help, so I can try to fix it.**

When trying to connect to a host locally, I enter the local hostname and then enter.local. It works just fine. When being outside the network (using external internet). I connect via an external IP address instead of the hostname followed by ":port#"(like 187.216.212.201:3389), but my iPhone(client) can't connect to the host, I receive the error code 0x204.

4. I tried all the external IP addresses I could get my hand on (the Google one, the modem router one) on my iPhone to connect to my PC windows.
5. I tried this service to check if my port is open, It is not. It keeps saying port is closed: https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/
6. I set up my IPV4 Address(local) to static IP via router settings + windows settings.
   *BTW, I use a Deco Modem Router which is very new and advanced (has lots of features). My host runs windows 10 lastest build.
7. I set up port forwarding on my modem router to go to my IP Address of my host. that has the same internal as external port(3389).

** Host is the desktop I want to connect to. The client is the iPhone I use to connect to the other desktop.

** The IP Addresses are random. soley for the purpose of the question.

Comment: Please get rid of the useless c\*ensoring.

Comment: Next time use the edit button :)

Comment: And edit it with what? Roll dice for each \*?

Comment: can you not read? *** The IP Addresses are random. soley for the purpose of the question.**

Comment: That's exactly my point. Random IP addresses are _completely useless_ for the purpose of the question. What are they supposed to do? Show what an IP address looks like? We already know what an IP address looks like. Either include enough of the actual address for it to be _useful_ or not include any address at all, instead of outright lying about "I get this IP".

Comment: @EyalCohen why don't you just use anydesk? its cool for that purpose

Comment: that's called calrification. @user1686

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll suppose there's some typo, because 187.276.292.301 is not a valid IP address (each part much be <= 255).

I can't tell what's happening in your specific situation, but it sounds like you do not have the right IP address, and/or the public address(es) that is (are) used to connect you to Internet aren't under your control.

This would typically be the case if you use a consumer-grade GSM connection (3G/4G/5G...).

You are going to need to:

- Identify which IP is your public IP.
- Identify how you can make sure incoming traffic on specific ports on that IP can be forwarded back to you.
  Likely your best option is your ISP or support forums for your ISP.

It might just be that it's not possible to do so. You might then rely on using some kind of intermediary hosts. For instance, you could setup a VPN, and have your RDP host connect to it.
You'd then connect your client to the same VPN, and then connect to your RDP over the VPN.
[Here's](https://golb.hplar.ch/2019/01/expose-server-vpn.html) one article on how to do so using Wireguard.

Comment: I used random for IP addresses. I use these IPs soley for question purpose

Comment: I don't use This would typically be the case if you use a consumer-grade GSM connection (3G/4G/5G...). I use VDSL connection(via wire).

Comment: I want to know Why I could not port forward my host PC.

Comment: It's not necessarily about YOU doing it. There is something called "CG-NAT" for instance that's usually applied on GSM connection. It's also applied on other networks. Assuming you have done your port forward properly, it should work. If it doesn't, likely the issue is somewhere else. The fact that your modem displays a different public IP from what you get on Google indicates your "public point out" is not using your modem's public IP, hence any forward you're doing there is useless.